# Counting elements in a matrix

Tags: python

I have this matrix:

```
matrix = [[a,r],[b,r],[c,r],[c,t,n],[b,t,n],[b,a]]
```

I want to count how many times did "n" appear in the matrix, but there is a condition. If the first letter is next to an "a" or an "r", it doesn't count as "n" appeared.
For example, in this list "n" appeared one time, because we have to discount the second time it appeared, due to the fact that the letter "b" later appeared next to an "a".

I've tried this:

```
c = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    if n in matrix[i]:
         c+=1
```

But I have failed in all the conditions that I've tried if the letter that is next to "n" appears again next to an "a"

Comment: Iliterate over list to get one more list and then illiterate over and check for first character and find the next to be n, while finding it add one to a counter variable and lastly print it!

Comment: Have you used numpy before? You probably should if working with matrices. Anyways it's not clear from your example: is `n` the string `'n'` or is it a variable. And if so, what does it contain?

Comment: "n" is the string inside the matrix

Comment: If 'n' and 'a' appear in the same 'chunk' (row?) - do they count?

Comment: "n" and "a" will never be in the same row

Comment: It doesn't answer your question in pure Python and hence this is just a comment, but you might find that NumPy will make working with Matrices easier. For example, using `where`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop over the matrix twice (as suggested in the comments) to first make an `ignore_list` to skip unwanted lists and then to count the number of `'n'`s. You can do this as follows -

```
matrix = [['a','r'],['b','r'],['c','r'],['c','t','n'],['b','t','n'],['b','a']]

c = 0
ignore_list = []
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    if matrix[i][1] == 'a':
         if matrix[i][0] not in ignore_list:
            ignore_list.append(matrix[i][0])

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    if matrix[i][0] not in ignore_list:
        if 'n' in matrix[i]:
            c+=1

print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that using sets:

```
matrix = [["a","r"],["b","r"],["c","r"],["c","t","n"],["b","t","n"],["b","a"]]

# get the indices of the items containing 'n'
n_inx = [inx for inx in range(len(matrix)) if 'n' in matrix[inx]]

# get the indices of the items containing 'n'
a_inx = [inx for inx in range(len(matrix)) if 'a' in matrix[inx]]

# create a list of these items +1 position and -1 position. 
a_inx = [[a-1, a+1] for a in a_inx]
a_inx = [inx for s in a_inx for inx in s]

# drop the 'n's that have 'a' next to them. 
len(set(n_inx).difference(a_inx))
```

The result is `1`.